# JAXB doesn't annotate with XmlRootElement

Tags: java, jaxb

When I generate code from the following schema, two classes are created, `A` and `B`. But, these two classes are not annotated by `@XmlRootElement`, so I get an error when I try to marshal an instance of B.

I've looked on the web, I tried the solution using custom bindings (`<xjc: simple/>`) but it doesn't work. It seems that an element of type B must be defined in the schema in order for this solution to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns:ns="com:mycomp:service" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="com:mycomp:service"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" xml:lang="EN">
    <complexType name="A" abstract="true">
        <sequence>
            <element name="a1" type="string" />
        <element name="a2" type="string" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="B">
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="ns:A">
            <sequence>
                <element name="b1" type="string" />
            </sequence>
        </extension>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Thanks

Comment: The following should help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, because your schema doesn't declare any root elements, only types.  If you want to marshal an instance of one of your `@XmlType`-annotated classes you will need to wrap that instance in a `JAXBElement` in order to tell the marshaller what element name to use:

```
// create context from the package name that contains your generated classes
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.mycomp.service");
Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement<B>(new QName("com:mycomp:service", "someB"),
      B.class, instanceOfB), outputStream);
```

This would produce something like

```
<someB xmlns="com.mycomp.service">
  <a1>foo</a1>
  <a2>bar</a2>
  <b1>baz</b1>
</someB>
```

Edit: you've commented that you're not doing the marshalling yourself but rather returning an object for a REST framework to marshal on your behalf. You may be able to use the same trick there by declaring your operation to return `JAXBElement<B>` instead of just `B`, but you're probably better off modifying the schema as suggested in other answers.

Comment: Maybe this could theoretically work, but I guess the generated document won't validate if you don't have a root element in your XSD.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I always see this code snippet (i.e. with the marshaller) but I don't how should I get a marshaller instance? Also, my method must return an instance of B and I don't see this in your example.

Comment: @MickaelMarrache Do you want to _marshal_ (start with an instance of B and end up with some XML) or _unmarshal_ (start with XML and end up with an instance of B). If the latter please edit your question with an example of the XML you have to start from.

Comment: I'm working in the context of a REST web service. I have an interface defining the methods for resource B. I've written a class that implements this resource interface. The GET method of this class returns for example a representation of an instance of B in XML. When I return the instance as is I get an exception since the class isn't annotated with @XmlRootElement. So, in this method, I only need marshalling to return the XML representation as a result. But, in another method (i.e. PUT), I may need to give a XML representation of my resource inside the request, i.e. unmarshalling.

Comment: I'll edit my answer for completeness, but in that case it looks like you will need to modify your schema to add some element declarations as suggested by the other answers. Beyond that it ceases to be purely a JAXB problem, so you should probably ask a separate question tagged for the appropriate framework or API (jax-rs, resteasy, whatever) including an example of your service code to reach the right audience.

Answer (score 1):

XJC will only generate the @XmlRootElement if the type of the top element in question (usually the single root element) is anonymous.

Eg. something like (untested):

```
<element name='B'>
   <complexType>
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="ns:A">
            <sequence>
                <element name="b1" type="string" />
            </sequence>
            </extension>
        </complexContent>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add `<element>` tag to your schema

```
<schema xmlns:ns="com:mycomp:service" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="com:mycomp:service"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" xml:lang="EN">
    <complexType name="A" abstract="true">
        <sequence>
            <element name="a1" type="string" />
        <element name="a2" type="string" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="B">
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="ns:A">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="b1" type="string" />
                </sequence>
            </extension>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>
    <element name="A" type="ns:A"/>
    <element name="B" type="ns:B"/>
</schema>
```

Comment: I don't think this will generate the @XmlRootElement. Are you sure? (See my answer.)

Comment: I'm not sure but What's the difference between your and my answers?

Comment: Your complexType B is top-level and can be reused. In my answer there is no complexType B, just a top-level element B with an anonymous complexType.

Comment: I can't add an element for each complex type since my schema is a standard one that I use with my service.